# What are the steps for migrating from Parse to Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: azure, parse-platform, azure-mobile-services

For those who've already migrated from Parse's Cloud Code to Azure's Mobile Services or those who have a good enough grasp of both to know how this would be done: Can you outline the high-level steps for migrating off of Parse and into Azure?

My concerns:

- Parse has an excellent ACL system but I wonder if there are scripts to translate it into Azure's DBs and tables.
- I wonder what's a close mock-equivalent of Parse's JS SDK so that I could Simply swap out Parse.*.* with Azure.*.* and still have code running seamlessly.
- Is this a pipe-dream?

Comment: @claes - no, seamless transition remains a pipe dream

Comment: Did you move forward in some other way?

Comment: @Claes - decided to use LoopBack.io and rebuild from ground up

Comment: Hello pulkitsinghal,
Have you successfully migrated your app DB from parse to Azure?

Comment: Nope. Gave up. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Parse enables you to export files in a JSON format.  You will find this feature under the Settings tab for your Parse app.

Comment: Yes exporting data out of parse begins with this step. But it is just a step, I'm fishing for a much bigger picture process.

Answer (score 0):

Since the announcement of the Parse shutdown, Microsoft has posted guidance on migrating from Parse here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/

Perhaps a bit too late for the OP but hope it helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.